# Cannot access to Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, kubernetes-dashboard

I have a K8s cluster (1 master, 2 workers) running on 3 vagrant VMs on my computer.

I've installed kubernetes dashboard, like explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started).

All my pods are running correctly:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP              NODE                   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-fb8b8dccf-n5cpm                       1/1     Running   1          61m   10.244.0.4      kmaster.example.com    <none>           <none>
coredns-fb8b8dccf-qwcr4                       1/1     Running   1          61m   10.244.0.5      kmaster.example.com    <none>           <none>
etcd-kmaster.example.com                      1/1     Running   1          60m   172.42.42.100   kmaster.example.com    <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-kmaster.example.com            1/1     Running   1          60m   172.42.42.100   kmaster.example.com    <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-kmaster.example.com   1/1     Running   1          60m   172.42.42.100   kmaster.example.com    <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-hcjsm                   1/1     Running   1          61m   172.42.42.100   kmaster.example.com    <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-klv4f                   1/1     Running   3          56m   172.42.42.102   kworker2.example.com   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-lmpnd                   1/1     Running   2          59m   172.42.42.101   kworker1.example.com   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-86qsw                              1/1     Running   1          59m   10.0.2.15       kworker1.example.com   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-dp29s                              1/1     Running   1          61m   172.42.42.100   kmaster.example.com    <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-gqqq9                              1/1     Running   1          56m   10.0.2.15       kworker2.example.com   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-kmaster.example.com            1/1     Running   1          60m   172.42.42.100   kmaster.example.com    <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard-5f7b999d65-zqbbz         1/1     Running   1          28m   10.244.1.3      kworker1.example.com   <none>           <none>
```

As you can see the dashboard is in "Running" status.

I also ran `kubectl proxy` and it's serving on `127.0.0.1:8001`.

But when I try to open  http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ I have the error:

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I'm trying to open the dashboard directly on my computer, not inside the vagram VM. Could that be the problem? If yes, how to solve it ? I'm able to ping my VM from my computer without any issue.

Thanks for helping me.

**EDIT**

Here is the ouput of `kubectl get svc -n kube-system`

```
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   96m
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    10.109.230.83   <none>        443:30089/TCP            63m
```

Comment: I assume you have full connectivity from your local machine to your vagrant vms. Did you check the kubernetes dashboard logs?

Comment: can you try this url. http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/overview?namespace=default

Comment: @EstebanGarcia what do you mean by "full connectivity" ? I can ping and ssh.

Comment: @SivaGnanam same error with this url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes dashboard runs only in the cluster as default. You can control it with get svc command:

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system
```

Default type of that service is ClusterIp, to reach from outside of the cluster yo have to change it to NodePort.
To change it follow [this doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above#nodeport).

Comment: I changed the type to NodePort. Do I access to the dashboard with the CLUSTER-IP displayed with `kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard` (which is 10.109.230.83) or with the IP of the master (which is 172.42.42.100) ? Actually in both cases I have `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`

Comment: no, cluster_ip can be used only in cluster. please share the output ot kubectl get svc -n kube-system